# Retrieving temporary code from Add to Slack button

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, slack-api, slack

I'm stalled midway through the Slack oauth process and could use some help. I have the Add to Slack button added to my website, and the next step according to the documentation is to retrieve a temporary code:

> If the user authorizes your app, Slack will redirect back to your specified redirect_uri with a temporary code in a code GET parameter

This code is need for the call to oauth.access, which will return the token I need. The Add to Slack button works as intended and sends me to a URL containing the code, but I can't figure out how to programmatically retrieve it using Python 3.5. I've been experimenting with the urllib library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler) as well as the requests library.

The root of my problem is that I need to retrieve a code from an unknown URL. Here's a link to the documentation I'm reading: https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Slack Documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth):

> Step 2 - Token Issuing
>   If the user authorizes your app, Slack will redirect back to your specified `redirect_uri` with a temporary code in a `code` GET parameter

Once you have authorized your app in the OAuth consent screen, Slack redirects you to the `redirect_uri` you passed to it in Step 1 or the one you set in the App configuration page.

On the server-side you will then need to read the `code` GET parameter to complete the OAuth Flow.

Here is a gist, which shows how to do basic Slack OAuth with Django: https://gist.github.com/xoneco/43cd18d5b991b8f5e288

[Line 27](https://gist.github.com/xoneco/43cd18d5b991b8f5e288#file-django-basic-slack-oauth-py-L27) onwards shows how you can implement the `redirect_uri` endpoint and finish the OAuth Flow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the code snippet you posted, do you know the origin of the `request` parameter passed to oauthcallback? I'm not sure how to find the proper URL to read its GET parameter, even though I can plainly see it through a browser.

Comment: The `request` parameter is passed to the function from Django. It includes the `GET` dictionary, which is the reason why I can retrieve the value of the `code` parameter. All GET request parameters are included in this dictionary ([Link for more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects)) What framework are you using for all of this at the moment?

Comment: At the moment we have no framework - just plain Python code and a website hosted through Amazon EC2. Will I need a framework to get my code online? If so, do you recommend Django? The end product will be a bot servicing many Slack teams simultaneously.

Comment: Well, technically you wouldn't need a framework, but I **highly** recommend having one. I would not know how to for example retrieve GET parameters from an incoming HTTP request without a framework such as Django. I do definitely recommend Django. It can easily serve many slack teams at the same time. In fact I am doing so with [Simple Poll](https://simplepoll.rocks) ;)

Comment: I may split this off into a separate question, but perhaps you could point me to a resource or guide. I've got a Django project running through EC2 now, but I can't seem to figure out where the code for my bot should actually live. Models.py seems like a possibility, but most tutorials state that this should be used just for data models only. TL;DR: where should my code be so Amazon/Django actually runs it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Definitely put this into a seperate question. At the beginning the code will probably live in views.py